# ImageView as background being pushed up by opening keyboard

Tags: android, background, imageview, android-relativelayout

As I'm using png as a background for my View I didn't want it to stretch in a weird way. So I put an ImageView inside RelativeLayout and set its parametrs to match parent.

The problem appears when I click on a edittext and keyboard is opening. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and keyboard pushes every view inside relative layout up, so my background image moves to. Do you know how to fix this?

Basically I want to adjust the view but not background image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
    tools:context="com.example.radzik.recipes.activity.LoginActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_activity_login" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar_login"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_email_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_thin_typeface_asset_path"
            android:text="EMAIL"
            android:textColor="@color/white_transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_email_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_condensed_typeface_asset_path"
            android:hint="example@gmail.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_thin_typeface_asset_path"
            android:text="PASSWORD"
            android:textColor="@color/white_transparent"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_view_password"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_condensed_typeface_asset_path"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />


        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sign_in"
            android:onClick="onLoginClicked"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" />

        <!--<Button-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/button_facebook_sign_in"-->
        <!--style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
        <!--android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"-->
        <!--android:onClick="onFacebookLogInClicked"-->
        <!--android:padding="10dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginRight="10dp"-->
        <!--android:text="Login with Facebook"-->
        <!--android:textStyle="bold"-->
        <!--android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>-->

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/button_facebook_login"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

       <!--  <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_facebook_login"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_facebook_log_in"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook_white_logo_custom_1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="36dp"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" /> -->

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_bottom_coloured_line" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_sign_up"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#040C12"
            android:onClick="onSignUpClicked"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="SIGN UP"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Background image: 
[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUbhd.jpg)

Comment: So you want to adjust your view but not background image?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Can you show your background image?

Comment: Have you use adjustPan attribute?

Comment: Like android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and set backround of relative parent layout.

Comment: It won't work this way, because image will become a bit flattened

Comment: Try to use android:scaleType="matrix" to imageview

Comment: Doesn't work that way

Comment: So why don't you crop your image accordingly?

Comment: I have also given an answer. Please try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Put you ImageView inside scrollview.

```
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/background_activity_login"/>
</ScrollView>
```

And in java set scrollview enabled false in onCreate method like below:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Works almost fine. Even with scrollview.setEnabled(false) I can move it

Answer (score 0):

Try not to add background in scroll view add another layout for background after scrollview  it work for me